# RecyclerView с SearchView и обработка кликов

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!

Создал `RecyclerView` с `SearchView` по [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview) инструкции. Помогите с организацией обработки нажатий. Использовал [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) метод, но когда ввожу значение в поиске, изменяется список и позиция элементов.

Например: если у нас будет список с алфавитом, то изначально буква *А* будет иметь `position = 0`, а если мы в поиске поставим букву *Я*, тогда она станет на позицию `0`.

Как организовать сохранение позиций, так-как мой следующий класс показывает информацию в зависимости от того, какой номер позиции ему передан?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте в адаптере список изначальных объектов. Не меняйте его при поиске и не отображайте.
2. По клику получайте позицию отображаемого объекта методом `indexOf(Object obj)` класса `ArrayList`.

   ```
   int positionInUNSORTEDlist = yoursInitialArrayListOfData.indexOf(/* сюда передайте объект отображаемый нажатым элементом списка в данный момент  */)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливайте обработку нажатий вот так:

```
    class ViewHolderHour extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        private final TextView hour;


        public ViewHolderHour(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            hour = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hour);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holderPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        }
    }
```